# Cannot running the file in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I jut got installed and learnd about automation. And then when I wanna run this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()    
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

there's an error like this line :

```
$ C:/Users/HELLO/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe d:/Lain-lain/belajarSele.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HELLO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 72, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "C:\Users\HELLO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\HELLO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child     
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Lain-lain\belajarSele.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "C:\Users\HELLO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\HELLO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

What should I do?

Comment: Hi. Did you check that you have proper path for chrome driver? Try this `webdriver.Chrome(path where you saved your chrome driver)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download `chromedriver` from [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=94.0.4606.61/)

and once downloaded, you should define in your code like this :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/*****/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
```